Can I get or insert (not upsert) a new document into a collection using one operation?
In MongoDB, I can do it by two operations(findOne+insertOne).
Note that upsert is not acceptable because I don’t want to modify the existing item.
This is a critical and frequent operation that I wish to optimize. Is that possible?
Put in another way, when undertone, it would be nice to return the duplicate item in the write error

The single database operation that looks for a document and inserts it if it doesn't exist is called an upsert.
The question as asked amounts to "How do I perform an upsert without doing an upsert?", which doesn't make sense.
I suspect the actual question should be more like "How do I perform an upsert without modifying the document if it already exists?
To execute that, you might use findAndModify with the match criteria in the query, in the update use only $setOnInsert, and in the options pass returnNewDocument: true.
If the document already exists, the $setOnInsert would not activate, so no change would be made to the document, returning the original document unmodified.
If the document does not already exist, the fields in the filter and $setOneInsert would be used to create and insert a new document, which would then be included in the command return.
Check the command return for upserted:true to see if the document was upserted.
